# How to generate a sql code that creates a view from others views?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a "General" view which an union of several "sub" views. I would like to be able to generate the code of the creation of the "General" view everytime a new "sub" view (NEW_SUB_VIEW) is added to the schema. 
The code for the "General" view is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "DV2_OBIDMT"."F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY" 
("SRC_SYS_ID", "SOFT_RULE_NAME", "ENTITY_NAME", "DATE_", "PASSES", "FAILS") 
AS 
( select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = 'SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ'
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))


UNION 

select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = 'SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ'
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))
```

I would like that the sql code generated would  add an UNION with the select of the new sub view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "DV2_OBIDMT"."F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY" 
("SRC_SYS_ID", "SOFT_RULE_NAME", "ENTITY_NAME", "DATE_", "PASSES", "FAILS") 
AS 
( select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = 'SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ'
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))


UNION 

select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = 'SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ'
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))

UNION 

select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, **NEW_SUB_VIEW**SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = '**NEW_SUB_VIEW**'
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))
```

I hope that was clear, Please help me with I'm not really that ggod in SQL, I don't know if I should add a trigger or create a procedure!

Thank you!

Comment: Creating a VIEW is a DDL command, i.e. Oracle performs an implicit `COMMIT` on it. This would automatically commit any current transaction. Would this fit into your business requirements?

Comment: The general view is an union of other views ( Select data from 2 views SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ and SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ ) and I want to add another Union select from a new view automatically 
without having to change the code of the general view each time I want to add a new sub view.

Comment: I wonder why you cannot just skip the `WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = ...` condition. Also you make a **CROSS JOIN** of  `IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES` and `SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ`, is this by intention? `(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_` is better replaced by `TRUNC(SRC.LDTS) as date_` and `DISTINCT` keyword use pointless when you use `UNION` or `GROUP BY`

Comment: "I wonder why you cannot just skip the `WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = ... `condition" --> Because I need to specify from which table I will get the data 
" `(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_  `is better replaced by  `TRUNC(SRC.LDTS) as date_ ` and ` DISTINCT ` keyword use pointless when you use  `UNION ` or  `GROUP BY ` " --> Thanks for the tip, it's works fine with  `TRUNC(SRC.LDT)  `

Comment: What do you mean by *everytime a new "sub" view (NEW_SUB_VIEW) is added*? An automatic detection of new views? Or do you prefer to execute a procedure manually (as you asked for **generate a code**, which means do not execute). What is the condition for *new view*? Perhaps any name pattern?

Comment: I have a table where I stock the name of the sub views that I create ( let's call it sub_views )  , and everytime a new sub view  is create I'll add it manually in the table _sub_views_ but I want it to be added automatically in the code of the "General" view by adding an `UNION` and change the `SELECT` code with `WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = 'NEW_SUB_VIEW'`and `From "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, NEW_SUB_VIEW SRC`. I think a procedure will be interesting but I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly the only part that is changing in your "subviews"
is the condition

`WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = '**NEW_SUB_VIEW**'`

if that is the case, why not implement your "general view" as

```
select distinct 
SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
EN.ENTITY_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY'))) as date_,
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Pass' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ SRC
WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME in (select view_name from my_current_views) 
GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'DD-MM-YY')))
```

And maintain a Table called **my_current_views**

```
create table my_current_views (
 view_name as varchar2(100)
)
```

And whenever you want your "general view" to change you insert new record into `my_current_views` table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong! I need to change 2 parts :
     WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = '**NEW_SUB_VIEW**' 
and     
    From "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, 
    **NEW_SUB_VIEW** SRC 

it's mostly the second one that is pretty hard to get !

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not very clear. Anyway, this trigger below will create new VIEW automatically every time a new view is added to your schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_NEW_VIEW 
    AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
    WHEN (ora_dict_obj_type = 'VIEW')
DECLARE 
    sqlcmd CLOB;
    entities VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE;
BEGIN    

    IF UPPER(ora_dict_obj_name) = 'F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY' THEN
        -- avoid recursive calling of this trigger!!!
        RETURN;     
    END IF;

    SELECT view_Name
    BULK COLLECT INTO entities 
    FROM NEW_SUB_VIEWS;

    -- "General view" components:
    entities := entities MULTISET UNION DISTINCT VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE('SAT_CNTRCT_OTH_GCP_DQ', 'SAT_CNTRCT_N4_DQ');

    sqlcmd := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW DV2_OBIDMT.F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY '||CHR(13);
    sqlcmd := sqlcmd ||'  (SRC_SYS_ID, SOFT_RULE_NAME, ENTITY_NAME, DATE_, PASSES, FAILS) AS '||CHR(13);
    FOR i IN entities.FIRST..entities.LAST LOOP
        IF i > 1 THEN
            sqlcmd := sqlcmd ||'UNION '||CHR(13);
        END IF;
        sqlcmd := sqlcmd ||'SELECT SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME, EN.ENTITY_NAME, TRUNC(SRC.LDTS) as date_, '||CHR(13)||
            'SUM(CASE WHEN SRC.QLTY_TEST= ''Pass'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Passes, '||CHR(13)||
            'SUM(CASE WHEN SRC.QLTY_TEST= ''Fail'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Fails '||CHR(13);
        sqlcmd := sqlcmd || 'FROM DV2_OBIADM.IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN '||CHR(13);
        sqlcmd := sqlcmd || '   CROSS JOIN '||entities(i)||' SRC '||CHR(13);
        sqlcmd := sqlcmd || 'WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = '''||entities(i)||''''||CHR(13);
        sqlcmd := sqlcmd || 'GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME, TRUNC(SRC.LDTS) '||CHR(13);
    END LOOP;   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlcmd); --> Just to verify and detect errors
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcmd;

END;
/
```

However, I think you should review your over-all design, it might be not the best one.